# How to access object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS .

so i want to be able to convert currency , especially IDR to USD.
and i want to use fixer.io . so here is my code :

```
function idr_to_usd(){
    var url = $.getJSON("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=IDR&symbols=USD");
    var respon = url.responseJSON;
    var rates = respon.rates.USD;
    return rates;
}
```

it doesn't work , in inspector it say :
**filename.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rates' of undefined**

but i try the code directly in inspector console and it work. so where did i do wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Read up on handling async operations in JS.

Comment: Call `JSON.parse(url)` after the Ajax call

Comment: `$.getJSON` does not return the URL, but a promise. Read about promises.

Comment: Did you mean json parse ? if i jsonparse the url , it will result to another error. 

i tried in browser console and it work, so how do i solve it in code?

Comment: @taek, check my answer. Its working for sure. I have checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution:

```
    var usd_rate = 0;
    function idr_to_usd(){
        $.getJSON('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=IDR&symbols=USD' , function(json_data){
            var rates = json_data.rates.USD;
            console.log(rates);    // check the console here.
            usd_rate = rates;
        });
    }

    idr_to_usd();
```

Comment: Where is `idr_to_usd()` defined?

Comment: @Mark_M, updated the answer.

Comment: it return "undefined"

Comment: It still won't work. You can't `return` from a callback like that. The return value of `idr_to_usd()` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Actually if you will console it, it will give you USD value. So actually there should be a global variable and USD value should be assigned to it. Let me update my answer for it.

Comment: It won't work. Now `idr_to_usd(); console.log(use_rate)` => `0`; You are ignoring the fact that `getJSON` is asynchronous.

Comment: You need to do something like: ` $.getJSON("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=IDR&symbols=USD", callback);  function callback(data) { var rate = data.rates.USD; console.log(rate)}`

Comment: Yes, now the updated answer works. Although there's no reason to assign the variable `usd_rate` because it won't be reliably available.

Comment: have you checked the code as I mentioned? @Mark_M

Comment: It is working for my every time. If its working for you guys, please up vote by accepting the answer. :-) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried it return undefined then return the rates, anyway Thanks for trying to help @HimanshuUpadhyay :)

Comment: It gives me `0.000075119` every time I execute the function. @taek

Comment: "gives" is not the same as "returns". The latter is an exact notion: the function returns `undefined`. It returns synchronously, while the rate will come asynchronously. BTW, this question has been asked numerous times, and all there is to know is in the linked answer that was used to close this question.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
function idr_to_usd(){
    var url = $.getJSON("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=IDR&symbols=USD");
    var respon = JSON.parse(url.responseText);
    var rates = respon.rates.USD;
    return rates;
}

alert(idr_to_usd());
```

Url is returning response text that is a *JSON object* but that is *stringify*

You have to convert your json string to json object so I am doing like as following

```
var respon = JSON.parse(url.responseText);
```

Now from response you can get rates.

Run following snippet if you are firing ajax result

```js
  function idr_to_usd(){
       $.getJSON("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=IDR&symbols=USD",function(data){
   var USD=data.rates.USD;
        alert(USD);
})
};

idr_to_usd()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not working, giving error in console.

Comment: Now try this will work

Comment: Remove `var url = `.

Comment: Removed 
    var url =

Comment: Bottom snippet will work